# "Too Many Arguments" with IF Function in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I keep getting an error that there's too many functions. What I'm trying to accomplish is IF there are hours listed in a specific column (Monday to Sunday), then take the date (in cell Y1) minus the correct number of days. Why won't it work?

```
=IF(M3<>"", $Y$1-6, "",IF(N3<>"", $Y$1-5, "", IF(O3<>"", $Y$1-4, "",IF(P3<>"", $Y$1-3, "",IF(Q3<>"", $Y$1-2, "", IF(R3<>"", $Y$1-1, "",IF(S3<>"", $Y$1, "")))))))
```

Comment: There is likely a better way to accomplish what you want. Can you [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1463646/edit) to add sample data and expected outcome? you can upload screencaps to http://imgur.com and link to them

Answer (score 2):

The nested if will go in the FALSE location of the parent IF:

```
=IF(M3<>"", $Y$1-6,IF(N3<>"", $Y$1-5,IF(O3<>"", $Y$1-4,IF(P3<>"", $Y$1-3,IF(Q3<>"", $Y$1-2, IF(R3<>"", $Y$1-1,IF(S3<>"", $Y$1,"")))))))
```

But that being said we can certainly make it more stream lined:

```
=$Y$1-7-MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(M3:S3<>"",),0)
```

The INDEX returns an array of TRUE/FALSE to the MATCH.  The MATCH returns the relative location in that array of the first TRUE.  We subtract that from 7 to get the correct value to subtract from Y1